# Changes to header when inserting different files using same template

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I'm using the Lesson Plan template to create separate plans, saved as separate files. When I insert the files into a larger Word doc, the individual lesson plan names (header) in the template are lost, defaulting to a single lesson plan name for all the inserted lesson plan files. Why is the autochange happening, and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1):

**Use of field codes could be your culprit.** It sounds as though the lesson plan names are displayed in the header in your individual Word documents because a `field code` is being used. This field code tells Word to display the name of the *current* document, which works as expected when the documents are separate. However, when you combine the individual documents into a new, single document, which has its own name, *that* name is used when the field code in the header is returned.

It's also possible the field code in use is returning the document's internal title, or still some other variable piece of data that is changing when the documents are combined.

**Bottom line:** Check the headers in the individual documents and if field codes are in use, consider changing them to actual text to prevent changes when the documents are combined.